Particular Solution to a stochastic differential equation
I am trying to solve the SDE
$$
\mathrm{d}X(t) = \sqrt{\left|X(t)\right|} \mathrm{d}W(t) + \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}t,
$$
where $W$ is a Brownian motion, with say, a given starting point $X(0)=x_0$. Playing a bit with Ito's formula (or better, Ito-Tanaka) it seems to me that $y(t):=2\sqrt{|X(t)|}$ satisfies (is it correct? this may be question "0")
$$
\mathrm{d}y(t) = \frac{1}{y(t)}\left(\text{sign}(X(t)) - \frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d}Z(t),
$$
where $Z(\cdot)$ is another Brownian Motion. In particular, if I could somehow guarantee that $X(t) > 0$ a.s. in a neighborhood, I would know that $y$ follows a 2D Bessel process there and I would be happy enough (as from there I can recover the distribution of $X$, at least in a neighborhood). So my questions are the following:

Is it possible to establish a result of that form, i.e., that there exists $x_0>0$ and $T=T(x_0)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X(t)<0) = 0\qquad \forall t\in [0, T]$ (does not really seem possible to me)?
Do solutions exist for $x_0 < 0$? If $X(t)$ is in a way "consistently negative" it feels a bit weird to have a negative drift term for $y$ (which must be positive).

Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!
